# Redox reactions KMnO4 changing to brown

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

If potassium permanganate is added to a solution and it becomes brown is the substance a reducing agent?

Comment: Attribute the brown color to a compound, compare oxidation states before and after, and you get the answer.

Comment: Permanganate is a strong oxidizier so most substances will be reducing agents in comparison. Even hydrogen peroxide.

Comment: Brown in potassium permanganate reactions usually means you formed MnO2.  The cure, If you want a nicer looking reaction forming Mn(II) ion in solution, is to add acid.  If you render the balanced equations for permanganate reduction, you find you need a lot of acid to get to Mn(II).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the substance is a reducing agent which will reduce $\ce{KMnO4}$ into $\ce{MnO2 }$ in neutral or weakly basic medium.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!! It'd be great if you could add a chemical reaction, that really adds value to an answer. It'd also be a great opportunity to learn how to use MathJax and mhchem => https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here